# How to build a multi-account-multi-user subscription based meteor app?

Tags: node.js, meteor, meteor-accounts

I want to build a webapp with meteor that groups users in roles, seperated in different accounts (companies).

```
account A
    user 1 (of role X)
    user 2 (of role X)
    user 3 (of role Y)
```

Is there any module/package setup that fits these needs, or should I develop from scratch?
I thought of using **alanning:roles**, but I did not test yet if their groups-definition may fit my needs for the account functionality.

Thnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@headkit how are we going to advise you without more information about your needs?

I would suggest that the alanning package is a good start, there is also a meteor app that you can use to administer users and roles that you can use (both will save you a bunch of time).

Rather than write something from scratch, look at the package, and ask whether it could be extended, either as a fork of the original package, or you could submit a PR.

Comment: I think I know how to achieve my needs now. I will go with the roles module first. thnx!

Comment: If you decide to contribute a fork I would be interested to know